# What is the difference between an API wrapper and a SDK?

Tags: api, sdk, wrapper

From my understanding, these two words are used almost interchangeably to refer to code that allows people to use a particular programming language to interact with an API. For example, many Python packages are labeled API wrappers or SDKs while providing essentially the same functionalities.

However, I am interested in hearing all of your opinions regarding the semantics of these two words.

Comment: Opinion-based questions are better asked in the Software Engineering Stack Exchange. See also this question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101873/whats-the-difference-between-an-api-and-an-sdk